# There are no pointers in Python; then how to bulk assing values to variables without repeating myself?

Tags: python

Consider this snippet:

```
key1 = 5
key2 = "5"

for key in [key1, key2]:
    if isinstance(key, int) or isinstance(key, float):
        key = str(key)

print(type(key1))
print(type(key2))
print(key1 == key2)
```

Of course it prints out:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
False
```

While I want to make certain that if `key1` is a number and `key2` is a string representing this number (or vice versa) they are both treated as equal.

Now I don't want to simply convert both keys to `str` because I don't want to have to consider in details what will happen if either key is a more complex type and if in such a case the comparison will still have the correct semantics. Hence the (unpythonic, isn't it? Sorry I'm kind of newbie to Python) type checking.

However, a naive implementation leads to code repetition:

```
if isinstance(key1, int) or isinstance(key1, float):
    key1 = str(key1)
if isinstance(key2, int) or isinstance(key2, float):
    key2 = str(key2)
```

It may be sufferable in this particual case, but if the comparison semantics grow and the conditions in `if` and/or conversions become more and more complex, then this repetition may become unacceptable.

However, this is Python, so of course I can't take a pointer to either key and operate on that. See the first snippet failing to provide correct semantics. And of course there are no `ref` parameters in Python either.

So, what is the correct way to avoid code repetition here?

EDIT: Since many people asked me for the bigger picture:

What I'm doing is, pretty much, fixing references. I'm dealing with an API that returns JSON objects. Sadly, this API is pretty much inconsistent and I have to deal with this.

For example, this API may return an object of this sort:

```
"GroupsOfFoo": [
{
    "group_id": '5',
    "group_name": "Awesome Group",
    "some_other_detail_of_the_group": {...}
}, {
    "group_id": '3',
    "group_name": "Joyful Group",
    "some_other_detail_of_the_group": {...}
}, ...
]

"Foos": [
{
    "foo_id": 'foo1',
    "group_id": 5,
    "some_other_detail_of_foo": {...}
},
{
    "foo_id": 'foo2',
    "group_id": 5,
    // Yep field "some_other_detail_of_foo" may be inconsisntetly present or absent but I'm digressing
},
{
    "foo_id": 'foo3',
    "group_id": 3,
    "some_other_detail_of_foo": False
},
...
]
```

So I'm now on my quest to fix these references. I want to add a field `foos` to the each group object that will be a list of foos of this group. Consistently, I want to make the field `group_id` in the foo object be a reference to the correct group and not an int or string.

Since we also have Groups of Bars and Groups of Bazs and whatever else, and in Bars the id of the group is `bar.info.type` and not `bar.group_id` as in foos, and since the code for fixing these references is getting repetitive in all those models already, I'm moving this code from all those models to a (pretty generic) function that takes a group object, list of members of this group, name of the attribute of the group that is the id of this group, name of the attribute of the member of the group that points to this group, quite a few other arguments that specify binding semantics...

And this function needs to compare the id of the group as present in the group object to the id of the group as present in the object representing a member of this group. Here I am.

Comment: There's probably an entirely different approach to the entire situation, but without seeing a bigger picture that's hard to say…

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Its seems like x vs y problem to me. And if this is exactly what youre trying to achieve, what's stoping your from iterating over a list of keys in a for block?

Comment: Also note: `isinstance(key1, (int, float))`…

Comment: @BoboDarph "what's stoping your from iterating over a list of keys in a for block?" - That's precisely what I'm doing in my first snippet, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: How about `if type(key1) in [int, float]: key1=str(key1)`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn But how do I loop over them? I'm trying to loop over them in my first snippet but it doesn't work!

Comment: Questions which amount to "how can I create lots of variables" almost invariably end up with the answer "don't; use a dict".

Comment: @gaazkam it would be nice to see the big picture of what you are trying to achieve. That said, you can pass the variables to a list and reference the list, instead of the variables. Use `for i, key in enumerate(keys): if isinstance(key, int):keys[i] = str(key) `

Comment: @tripleee But where am I creating lots of variables? is 2 variables already "lots of"?

Comment: Hmm, together with @deceze's comment, I'd say use a list comprehension: `keys = [str(key) if isinstance(key, (int,float)) else key for key in keys]`.

Comment: If you're repeating the same code for variables which literally just differ in an ending "1" or "2"… yeah, that's already "lots" (more than one) and warrants a list, or perhaps tuple. In computing there's 0, 1 and "more than 1"; there's no magical number between 2 and 20 where "lots" starts.

Comment: You talk about "bulk assignment" (sic) and "repeating yourself". The other common answer is "create a class".

Comment: Make your own class. Parsing list of jsons should be trivial. You can check existence of a key with `if key in json.keys()` and take it from there. Make your own objects out of the API response and work with those.

Comment: @BoboDarph Yes precisely! I do have my own class! In fact, I have many classes: a class called `GroupOfFoos`, a class called `Foo`, a class called `GroupOfBars`, a class called `Bar`, a class called `GroupOfBazs`, a class called `Baz`... And now class `GroupOfFoos` contains the method `bind_to_foos()`, class `GroupOfBars` defines `bind_to_bars()`, class `GroupOfBazs` defines`bind_to_bazs()`... And this is geting repetitive.

Comment: @BoboDarph Since all those classes inherit from `Model`, I'm moving the code of `bind_to_...` methods to `Model.bind` and instead making `bind_to...`s call `Model.bind`. with correct args. Still, the amount of genericity required in `Model.bind` is getting daunting

Comment: "don't want to have to consider in details what will happen if either key is a more complex type" what do you want to happen? the complex type to define their own comparison (to what)?  automatically be interpreted as False even if string representations match?

Comment: @user24343 The key may already be bound. In that case I want the default reference comparison, NOT converting an instance of `GroupOfFoos` to string.

Comment: @user24343 To elaborate: Some models (and some `GroupsOf...`) do override `__str__`. This is what I don't want to have to consider: If the comparisons will still be correct given how a particular group converts to string.

Comment: @gaazkam So how do you want to compare to a model? Do they also define ``__eq__``?

Comment: @user24343 Perhaps they should. But I'll think about it later. For now, falling back to identity comparison is enough.

Comment: @gaazkam So you'd like something as ``any(str(k1)==str(k2), k1==str(k2), str(k1)==k2, k1==k2)``? (``==`` defaults to ``is``). You should be able to rewrite that with a generator, using ``set(itertools.permutations((1, 1, 0, 0), 2))`` and ``k1 if cond1 else str(k1)`` with ``cond1, cond2`` being in the set, but that might be more complicated than simple ``or``

Answer (score 0):

Just do in-line casting without assigning the casted values to the variables. Like this:

```
key1 = 5
key2 = "5"

print(type(key1))
print(type(key2))
print(key1 == key2)
print(str(key1) == str(key2))
print(int(key1) == int(key2))
```

Of course, if you have a leading zero on the string, e.g. key1 = "05" and key2 = 5 then str(key1) == str(key2) will return False, whereas int(key1) == int(key2) will return True.

Comment: From my Q: "Now I don't want to simply convert both keys to str because I don't want to have to consider in details what will happen if either key is a more complex type and if in such a case the comparison will still have the correct semantics. Hence the (unpythonic, isn't it? Sorry I'm kind of newbie to Python) type checking."

Comment: @gaazkam fair enough. What are you actually trying to achieve here? What's the bigger picture, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your snippet, if you parsed it with `json.loads` it looks like you would end up with a list of dicts, which is pretty much the ideal situation for this.

something like

```
for item in my_json_list:
    # item here is a dict
    if 'group_id' in item.keys(): # check whether the key is in this dict
        item['group_id'] = str(item['group_id'])
        # cast the value as a str (if it's a string to start with it doesn't change)
```

since lists and dictionaries are mutable changing the object you're referring to will change it in the list / dictionary (in some senses there are no pointers in python, but in some senses everything in python is a pointer..)